# What does this code means in R? full$Title <- gsub('(.*, )|(\\..*)', '', full$Name)

Tags: r, feature-engineering

````
```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
# Grab title from passenger names
full$Title <- gsub('(.*, )|(\\..*)', '', full$Name)

# Show title counts by sex
table(full$Sex, full$Title)
````

Comment: See [`?regex`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html).

Answer (score 1):

`(.*, )` -> means any text before and including a comma and space. It will match "test, " in "test, dummy"

`(\\..*)` -> means anything after and including a dot. It will match ".dummy" in "test.dummy"

`(.*, )|(\\..*)` -> means matching first OR second pattern

So it will transform something like "test, dummy.something" into "dummy" by replacing matched text with ""